# How to remove a white background from copy-pasted content in Rich Text Editor in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, copy-paste, rich-text-editor

When I copy and paste my content into Sitecore's Rich text Editor it appears on the white background for some reason.

How can I remove that white background from the copy-pasted content?

Comment: How do you paste your content -  using “Paste as Plain Text” or “Paste from Word” option?

Answer (score 0):

Try ctr+shift+v or cmd+shift+v (for mac)

otherwise:

1. You can manually remove the background color from the copied
   content by selecting the content and then clicking on the "Clear
   Formatting" button in the formatting toolbar.
2. You can set the
   default background color for the Rich Text Editor to transparent. To
   do this, go to the "Appearance" tab in the Rich Text Editor settings
   and set the "Background color" field to "Transparent".